# on which node will elasticsearch.yml apply in a multi-node cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and want to add another node to a 3-node elasticsearch production cluster and to change configuration for tuning.

I am wondering on which node elasticsearch.yml will override ones on other nodes when elasticsearch.yml files differ by node? One on the master node? Or one on the last node added to the cluster? Or should I update all elasticsearch.yml files to have the same configuration.

Regards,

Comment: Not necessarily the same config, for instance, master-only nodes (`master:true`+ `data: false`) will not have the config as data-only nodes (`master:false`+ `data: true`). There are also other config settings that might differ depending on the decisions you make.

Comment: Thank @Val. I want to understand in which order configuration applies when there are conflicting ones.

Comment: The config of each node is meant for that node only.Each node works in isolation even while being part of a cluster.Addition of a new node doesn't cause any conflict or overriding of existing node configs.

Comment: May be specify your concerns in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config of a node is applicable for that node only. So in essence,Each node works in isolation even while being part of a cluster.

When a new node is added,the following can happen-

- If the next node is going to be a Data Node (master:false,data:true)
  ,as soon as the node gets into a cluster,the master node will get
  notified of the new data node in the cluster and will also start
  storing data in the new node apart from the other existing data
  nodes.
- If the next node is Master eligible(master:true,data:false),once it joins the cluster,nothing much happens. However,when the exisiting
  Master node goes down,this new node may become a MASTER.(Depends on
  whether any other node in the cluster is also master node.)
- If the next node is MASTER eligible as well as data node,the combination of the above two happens.

So,addition of new nodes does not require changes in the config of existing nodes. Just make sure the properties of the new node are set up as required and you are good to go.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!